Model inheritance with existing DB models. Migration issue with “_prt” field
I’ve started to refactor some legacy code and having some difficulties with Model Multi-Table Inheritance on existing model.
Let’s say I have a parent class Item:
class Item(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(ItemCategory, null=True, blank=True)

I have a child classes such :
class Phone(Item):
    serial_number = models.CharField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Vacuumcleaner(Item):
    power = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Cpu(Item):
    frequency = models.InteferField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

Finally I want to be able to enclose some Item instance in another model. For example :
class Computer(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToMany(Item)

For a transition period I’ve allowed Item fields to be null=True and blank=True for a later manual population. However during a migration call I receive it is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'item_ptr' to phone without specifying a default. I understand a nature of this warning as django doesn’t know where to link item_ptr which hides under the hood and links to Item model with OneToOne relation. So I have a dummy Item instance I want to use for linking but how to point the Item id/pk on the console with choosen option 1 as it doesn’t recognize raw int as pk. Is it possible overall or the way is to manipulate with migrations manually?
I don't see the option of dropping DB as it's already contains important data.
Update 1:
Previously I had several models like Phone, Laptop, Vacuumcleaner etc.
The first point of refactor : all the models have fields duplicates like brand, model, category.
The second and the main point: I need to make feature of writing off the "device/item" from stock. And it gets hard when there is a Computer model which consist of "device/item" which assembled on a store side and all components like CPU, Motherboard are a part of stock-items. Even some screw may be a Item as well as object to write off. So the code is difficult to maintain and to scale.
So idea is to implement Multi-Table inheritance or Item FK relation to link each product to Item to make it universal model which kept on stock and may be writen off.

Uhh, was Phone not inheriting from Item previously? If not you'd likely be better off not adding multi table inheritance into the mix.

Why did you let Phone inherit from Item?

@willeM_VanOnsem, sorry for unclear question as I want to provide short example. However I've updated my question with more detals. Thanks for response

The above implementation will create duplicate  since it means Item fields will be duplicated across the other models, ie, Cpu, Phone. To avoid this, I suggest the use of a defined one-to-one relationship in the other tables, ie,
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Item(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True)

class Phone(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='phone')
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Cpu(models.Model):
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='computer')
    frequency = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

this way, you've control of the item value either on save (you can override save() and pass a default item) and also avoids duplication. The above implementation will results to 

But share the mutual fields from parent model is what I want. Is inheritance will not create OneToOne relation by default?

for mutual fields, you can mark the Item class as an abstract class to avoid django creating an Item table in the db.

I'm aware of abstract models. However I need an individual table for Item as it has to contain a rest of "items" such as screw or tape for example.
